# convert useful information from eclipse printout into defined variable

Tags: android, eclipse, android-wifi

i have developed an application that is able to scan for the existing wifi signals surrounded my device and show their names and their strength as well as follow  :

```
    tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

    List <ScanResult> results = wm.getScanResults ();
  String otherwifi="The existing network is:\n\n";

   for (ScanResult result: results) {  
    otherwifi+=result.SSID+":"+result.level+"\n";
    tv.setText (otherwifi);

   }
```

where result.SSID is the router name and result.level is the signal strength 
now i only want to  get 3 specific wifi signal strength out of the scan list and define them as a variable in eclipse to use them for further process ?

Your help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The level you are getting is of int type so u can use switch like this:-

```
List<ScanResult> specificList = new ArrayList<ScanResult>();

for(ScanResult result:results) 
{

//SpecificLevel1, SpecificLevel2 and SpecificLevel3 are your predefined constants that you want to use.

    switch(result.level)
    {
    case SpecificLevel1 :
          specificList.add(result);
          break;

    case SpecificLevel2 :
          specificList.add(result);
          break;

    case SpecificLevel3 :
          specificList.add(result);
          break;

    }
}
```

Now you have a list of results which only includes your specific items. this List can be accessed any where you want it.

Comment: thanks for your feed back 
i used what you suggested but it shows error in using "case" , the type of error is duplicate case .. what i suppose to do 

@Taranmeet

Comment: What are the values u are using for SpecificLevel1, SpecificLevel2 and SpecificLevel3... ?

Comment: actually i want to use them as wifi signal strength 
for example SpecificLevel1 as wifi strength for router 1, SpecificLevel2 as wifi strength for router 2 and so on 
hope you get my point